# Components of tangent vector fields to curves on manifolds induced by a chart.

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $\gamma: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow M$ be a curve on $M$ and $(U,x)$ be a chart on $M$. If $\gamma(0)=p$ is a point on $U\subseteq M$, $X_{\gamma,\gamma(0)}$, the tangent vector to $M$ at $p$ along $\gamma$ is defined via its action on a smooth map $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow M$ in the following way.

$X_{\gamma,\gamma(0)}f:=(f\circ\gamma)'(0)$

In a chart induced basis of $T_pM$, the tangent space to $M$ at $p$, induced by $(U,x)$, the components of $X_{\gamma,\gamma(0)}$ are determined as follows.

$X_{\gamma,\gamma(0)}f:=(f\circ\gamma)'(0)=(f\circ x^{-1}\circ x \circ \gamma)'(0)$

$=\partial_a(f\circ x^{-1})(x(p))(x^a\circ \gamma)'(0)$

$=\dot{\gamma}^a_{(x)}(0)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^a}(x(p))$

where $\dot{\gamma}^a_{(x)}:=(x^a\circ \gamma)'$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^a}:=\partial_a(f\circ x^{-1})$

Here, $\dot{\gamma}^a_{(x)}$ is a map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}$ is a derivation on the algebra of $C^{\infty}$ functions on $M$.

When one considers the case of vector fields on manifolds, the components are chosen as the $C^{\infty}$ functions on $M$. What should then be the components of tangent vector fields of curves on a manifold? This distinction is important when one considers the derivations of objects on manifolds such as the autoparallel equation, where one considers the action of the tangent vector field on their own components.

Comment: Talking about autoparallel equation requires the datum of what is called a connection. It is not defined otherwise.

Comment: Of course, while deriving the autoparallel equation of a given connection/covariant derivative in a chart, there comes a point where we must act on the component functions of the tangent vector field to the curve by the tangent vector field itself. This is, however, not well defined unless the components are smooth functions on the manifold.

Comment: Then, I don't get what your question is

Comment: What must the component functions of tangent vector fields to curves on a manifold be?

Comment: $\gamma \colon I \to M$ is a smoot curve if in any chart, it is a smooth curve from $I$ to an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Its tangent field $\gamma'(t)$ is a smooth function from $I$ to $TM$ with $\gamma'(t) \in T_{\gamma(t)}M$.

A vector field *along the curve* $\gamma \colon I \to M$ is a *smooth* section of the vector bundle over $I$:
$$
\gamma^*(TM) = \{(t,v) \mid v \in T_{\gamma(t)}M \}
$$
Hence, is is a *smooth* function $X \colon I \to TM$ with $X(t) \in T_{\gamma(t)}M$. By definition, it is smooth, and in a local frame, the components of $X$ are smooth function of $t$.